# When the database is updated the program freezes

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfilemanager

There is a database that lists the files in documents directory (objective c - core data).  This list is updated every time the program is opened. With 700 number of files, the program takes 30 seconds to open and clicking on a button does not respond at all during this time.

I could not find a way to do this in the background. Is there a way of doing slowly forcing the processor (cpu)? So while the user continues to use the program, let it update in the background.

```
- (void)Reload_Data    
{
      id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

      NSManagedObjectContext *context = [delegate managedObjectContext];

       NSDirectoryEnumerator *directoryEnumerator = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] enumeratorAtPath:kDocdir];

    for (NSString *pathi in directoryEnumerator){
        NSString *path = [self kDoc_dosya:pathi];

        NSError *error_iki;
        NSDictionary *file_propery = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:path error:&error_iki];

        if (!error_iki && ![[path lastPathComponent] hasPrefix:@"."] && [file_propery fileType] != NSFileTypeDirectory) {

           NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
           NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:Parcalar_s inManagedObjectContext:context];
           [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

            NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"url LIKE [cd] %@",[self Doc_Sil:path]];
            [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
            [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:1];
            [fetchRequest setFetchLimit:1];

            NSError *error = nil;
            NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

            if (!error && [fetchedObjects count] < 1) {
               Parcalar *parca = (Parcalar *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:Parcalar_s inManagedObjectContext:context];
               parca.url = [self Doc_Sil:path];

                AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] options:nil];
               NSUInteger suresi = CMTimeGetSeconds(asset.duration);
               parca.sure = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:suresi] ;

            }
        }
   }


    NSError *error = nil;   if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) [self Alert_Uyari:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]]];

}
```

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean you cannot find a way to achieve this in the background?

That's quite simple and you can do it in a number of different ways.

- `NSOperation`
- Grand Central Dispatch
- Core Data new iOS 5 API

A simple example could be the following (GCD)

```
dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{
   // create a new context for background execution and assign it the persistent coordinator grabbed form the main context
   NSManagedObjectContext *backgroundContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
   backgroundContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = persistentStoreCoordinator;

   // do your stuff here

   NSError *error;
   if (![backgroundContext save:&error])
   {
      // handle error if necessary
   }
});
```

where `backgroundQueue` is a queue that belongs to GCD grabbed like

```
dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
```

So, when you load the app call `reloadData` method like the above. When finished, fire a notification to notify the user the import has finished.

Following GCD and `NSOperation`s, you also need to merge changes from the background context. This is not necessary with new CD new API using parent/child contexts.

In the following you can find some links on the subject.

- [Multi Contexts Core Data](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/)
- [Core Data with multiple managed object contexts](http://www.slideshare.net/xzolian/core-data-with-multiple-managed-object-contexts)
- [IMPORTING AND DISPLAYING LARGE DATA SETS IN CORE DATA](http://www.cimgf.com/2011/08/22/importing-and-displaying-large-data-sets-in-core-data/)

Comment: *flexaddicted* addresses you provide is very nice. Thank you very much.
I wonder if I add this problem only shall we?


    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    //context.parentContext = contextIWantToBeParent;
    context.persistentStoreCoordinator = [delegate persistentStoreCoordinator];
    
    [context performBlock:^{
    
    }];

Comment: Sorry, I cannot understand what you are asking. Could you explain better? Thanks